# Mongo with Express: what does find return

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am developing an application in `Express` with `Mongo`,  in which i have to `query`, whether a `document` exits in the `collection` or not. I am doing this:

```
var dept= req.body.dept;
var name= req.body.name;
mongoose.model('User').find({'dept': dept, 'name': name}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            res.render('user/test1');
        }else{
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is to check if that `document` exits in the `collection` and upon true `condition`, i want to redirect to another page otherwise render the current page. But when I pass the wrong `input`, even then it goes to the `else` part and `redirects` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are actually using [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/), so there is in fact a distinction between what is returned by this specific version ( abtraction ) to what the base driver itself returns.

In the case of `mongoose`, what is returned is either an `array` of results or a `null` value if nothing is found. If you are looking for a singular match then you probably really want [`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead of a result array.

But of course the case would be a `null` result with either function if not returned as opposed to an `err` result that is not `null`, which is of course about specific database connection errors rather than simply that nothing was found.

The base driver on the other hand would return a ["Cursor"](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find) ( or optionally considered a promise ) instead, which can either be iterated or converted to an array like mongoose does via the [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) method. The `.findOne()` method of the base driver similarly returns either a result or a `null` document where the conditions do not match.

```js
mongoose.model('User').findOne({'dept': dept, 'name': name}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        // if an error was actually returned
    } else if ( !user ) {
        // Nothing matched, in REST you would 404
    } else {
        // this is okay
    }
});
```

In short, if you want to test that you actually found something, then look at the `user` value for a value that is not `null` in order to determine it matched. If it is `null` then nothing was matched.

So no match is not an "error", and an "error" is in fact a different thing.